# cellForItemAtIndexPath of collectionView is not called when I reload the cells from a method of another class(navigationviewcontroller)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a viewController in which i am implementing a collection view. I have set the delegate and datasource of the collection view too inside the viewDidLoad of viewController.The action I was trying to implement was if I click a button on a navigationBar(which was implemented programatically in navigationViewC) it should reload the collectionView cells in the ViewController.But if I add action selector to the navigation bar button as function in navigationViewController but reloads the data of Collection View it is not calling cellForItemAtIndexPath method.Can someone help me please

Comment: can you check this  if(yourCollectionView) {   then only reload your collection view}

Answer (score 0):

you should add that barbuttonitem in your regular viewcontroller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Reload", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "reloadButtonTapped")
}

func reloadButtonTapped() {
    println("reload")
}
```

Comment: I want the bar button on my navigation bar which ll be visible all through the app. And I have tried with your idea too.It is not working :(

Comment: In this case, `target` must be the **view-controller's object** (containing the collection-view), not the `self`.